# Convert a MySQL query with a subselect to a single query using a join

Tags: mysql

How would I convert this query into a query that uses a join instead:

`SELECT pm.name,(SELECT chapter FROM puzz_chapter WHERE (grup = 1 OR grup2 = 1) AND manga = pm.mangaId ORDER BY chapterId DESC LIMIT 1) as sonbolum FROM puzz_manga as pm;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a join, you would move the subquery in a `left join` clause, like this:

```
select    pm.name,
          pc.chapter as sonbolum  
from      puzz_manga pm
left join (select  manga, chapter 
          from     puzz_chapter 
          where    (grup = 1 or grup2 = 1) 
          order by chapterId desc
          limit    1) pc
       on pc.manga = pm.mangaId;
```

But maybe you are looking for a way to avoid the sub query. In that case there is no efficient way to do this in MySql (at the time of writing). One way is to use `group_concat`, and then extract the first value from it, but I expect this to be less efficient than the solution you already have:

```
select    pm.name,
          substring_index(group_concat(pc.chapter order by pc.chapterId desc), ",", 1) 
                 as sonbolum
from      puzz_manga pm
left join puzz_chapter pc
       on (pc.grup = 1 or pc.grup2 = 1) 
      and pc.manga = pm.mangaId
group by  pm.mangaId;
```

See both queries run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/EFT10821)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I LOVE THIS PLATFORM <3333